# Open two applications in full spit screen using Bash script

Tags: terminal, applescript, bash, split-view

I am trying to write a Bash script to open two applications in full split screen, for example:

```
#!/bin/bash

LESSON="$1"

echo operating on lesson $LESSON

open /Applications/Pages.app /Users/username/Library/Mobile\ Documents/com~apple~Pages/Documents/$LESSON*
open /Users/username/courses/chemistry/$LESSON*
```

This works, but I want to open Pages and Preview in full screen and split view.

Answer (score -1):

Get the [Magnet](https://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/magnet/id441258766?mt=12) app from the App Store, far less effort and does exactly what you want.

Comment: I have yet Magnet and I use it every days. There is no massochism, the actual massochims is open the same PDFs every days ad put them manually firstly full screen and then in split view. A simple click-launchable script make life easier. 

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this issue?